# How to render ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) differently?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

My application has an REST interface and I must customize the rendering of the result body in case that a controller returns `ResponseEntity<>(NOT_FOUND)` as the controller with the following method it does:

```java
@Override
public ResponseEntity<ScimCoreUser> getUserById(String userid) {
    Optional<ScimCoreUser> result = service.findUserByNumber(userid);

    return result.map(user -> new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK))
                 .orElseGet(() -> new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
}
```

I cannot change the signature of the method, as I must impement a generated interface. I know what I could simple throw a custom exception and handle this exception with a controller advice.

Does someone know how to take over the rendering of the result body for `ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND))`, so that I can return an error message in the following format as defined in [RFC 7644: System for Cross-domain Identity Management: Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7644#section-3.12):

```json
{
    "schemas": ["urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error"],
    "detail":"Resource 2819c223-7f76-453a-919d-413861904646 not found",
    "status": "404"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### SCIM protocol & Spring

Not experienced with SCIM but found a related question:
[SCIM implementation for Spring Boot SAML and OKTA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62001848/scim-implementation-for-spring-boot-saml-and-okta)

#### Spring response magic: extension points

For "rendering", or **converting** response-entities to HTTP responses Spring uses subclasses of `HttpMessageConverter`. This *bean* would be a candidate to define and inject in your web-config.

Spring allows to enrich/extend the **error-attributes** converted and sent as error-response:
[Spring Boot customize http error response?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236811)

The **error-messages** used for enriching a HTTP error response body like NOT_FOUND (404) are either defined by a message-bundle (properties file with I18N support) or set within the response filter-chain.

The actual *rendering*, if JSON, plain text,  HTML, etc. is done by Spring upon **content-negotiation** with requesting HTTP-client.
However, you could override the method in controller and specify parameters *consumes*, *produces* to `@RequestMapping` annotation.

Comment: I step through the code and Spring calls only a message converter, if the body, that is, the payload, if not null. In my case the message is null and therefore no message converter is called.

Comment: @Oliver Sorry I didn't research further. So, could you add a body to trigger the _converter_? Otherwise some status-code serialisation is certainly performed by Spring too!?

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
return result.map(user -> new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK))
                 .orElseThrow(() -> 
                      new ResponseStatusException(
                            HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "User not found");
```